# Angular with Coffescript not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript

My prefered development environment is straight coffeescript and this has treated me well until I started getting into AngularJS. For some reason my current setup will not run correctly with coffeescript.

Here's the deal, this works:

```
//Jade:
script(type='text/javascript', src='/js/coffee-script.js')
script(type='text/javascript', src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js')
script(type='text/javascript', src='/js/grndCntrl.js')
```

but not this:

```
//Jade:
script(type='text/javascript', src='/js/coffee-script.js')
script(type='text/javascript', src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js')
script(type='text/coffeescript', src='/js/grndCntrl.coffee')
```

I know that my coffeescript translation is valid and if I convert that coffeescript to js it works just fine in the js file.

What I suspect is that it has something to do with coffee-script.js not converting the file before Angular gets ahold of it, but I really don't have much of a grasp how that works.

Any suggestions on how to get back to write coffeescript for Angular??

Comment: Is there a reason you do not precompile to javascript? It eliminates a dependency and these side effects.

Comment: See my [answer and comment](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17498509/1095616) on a similar question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just started using [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com) to pre-compile with grunt-watch and grunt-coffee