# Unable to CoffeeScript AngularJS module to load with ng-app in JSFiddle

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, jsfiddle

I'm playing around with Coffeescript and AngularJS, trying to use the new "controller as" syntax. Despite varied attempts and searching Google, I can't get it to work - the controller reference in my html doesn't find the Coffeescript class for the controller.

I suspect I am doing something wrong or just misunderstanding things but if anyone has a working example, it would be very helpful.

Here's a little jsfiddle showing what I am trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/G2r4p/ (the controller in this example is just an empty dummy controller so I can test the syntax).

When I run this example in my browser I get:

```
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'AppController' is not a function, got undefined
at hasOwnPropertyFn (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular.js:60:12)
at assertArg (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular.js:1187:11)
at assertArgFn (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular.js:1197:3)
at $get (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular.js:5547:9)
at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular.js:5060:34
at forEach (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular.js:203:20)
at nodeLinkFn (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular.js:5047:11)
at compositeLinkFn (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular.js:4607:15)
at compositeLinkFn (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular.js:4610:13)
at publicLinkFn (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular.js:4516:30)
```

Thanks

Comment: Updated the title and added the JSFiddle tag to this question so hopefully it gets the JSFiddle team's attention.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17498509/1095616) to [Why do I need to angular.bootstrap even when I declare ng-app=“MyApp” in JSFiddle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17496599/why-do-i-need-to-angular-bootstrap-even-when-i-declare-ng-app-myapp-in-jsfiddl/17498509#17498509), and this working fork of your JSFiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) is the culprit. Your syntax is correct and works fine as is when I tried it in [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/). It looks like JS Fiddle is processing something out of order, compared to JS Bin, which doesn't suffer from this issue.

Check out the working JS Bin example: http://jsbin.com/akABEjI/1/edit

You might also be interested in my blog post that takes the AngularJS Todo app and converts it to CoffeeScript: ["Writing AngularJS controllers with CoffeeScript classes."](http://softwareninjaneer.com/blog/2013/09/08/writing-angularjs-controllers-coffeescript-classes/) Ultimately your sample is similar to what I end up with in my final example.

Comment: I've seen that already (very useful and clear it was too). What I can't work out is what on earth I've done wrong!

Comment: Got it, thanks to you blog. I gradually removed things until it stoppe working. The issue is that when I was trying it, I was registering the controller in a separate file to the controller definition, ie I had the call to .controller("AppController", AppController) in a different file to AppController.coffee. Presumably due to the coffeescript scoping, the controller was not being registered properly.

Comment: @matthelliwell glad it helped. It was tricky getting CoffeeScript classes working initially, which led me through that step by step process of slowly building up to it.

Comment: @AhmadMageed Thanks for the post and blog. I would like to use coffeescript classes but want to avoid the "controller as" since I'm defining routes in module.config.  Is this possible?

Comment: @bob the second-last example on my blog demonstrates the controller without the `as` syntax. Here's the [direct JS Bin link to the example](http://jsbin.com/eJOVofO/4/edit?html,js,output). Hope that helps!

Comment: @AhmadMageed Thanks again - that did help. Now I'm struggling to extend it to capture $http return data but that is a different issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed a bit your code and it is working now (http://jsfiddle.net/denisonluz/r5KQb/2/)

Also bear in mind that sometimes can be a bit tricky to make AngularJS work when using JSFiddle. There's a good post [here](http://pkozlowskios.wordpress.com/) about it. When using AngularJS and CoffeScript on JSFiddle you must use manual bootstrap.

**COFFESCRIPT**

```
testApp = angular.module 'testApp', []

testApp.controller 'AppController', ($scope) ->
    $scope.items = [{title: "My test App", description: 'Some Text Here'}]

angular.bootstrap document, ["testApp"]
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller='AppController'>
<h3>one plus two is {{1 + 2}}</h3>
  <ul ng-repeat='item in items'>
    <li>{{item.title}}</li>
    <li>{{item.description}}</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Putting aside the jsfiddle problem, which is an unfortunate red herring, I can get the code going like your example as well. However, I am trying to get the "controller as" syntax to work so the view can access my controller class directly, rather than using $scope. There's a good video about it here: http://www.thinkster.io/pick/GmI3KetKo6/angularjs-experimental-controller-as-syntax

Answer (score 0):

#### The problem isn't your CoffeeScript, it's JSFiddle.

The problem is that the way JSFiddle is doing CoffeeScript, **it's processing the CS and executing the created JavaScript well after Angular tries to bootstrap the app with your ng-app="TestApp" directive.**

While @dluz, "solves" this problem, it doesn't explain it.

One solution is to bootstrap your app manually, as @dluz suggests, but you won't have to, and shouldn't have to, do this in a production environment.

Ideally, in a production environment, you'd be pre-processing your CoffeeScript and it would never be compiled to JavaScript in the browser, as it is in JSFiddle.

Comment: Trouble is, I get the same problem if I transpile the Coffeescript and run it on a local server so whilst jsfiddle may be adding an unnecessary level of complexity, I've still got the problem. With hindsight, I should've just posted the code sample and left jsfiddle out of it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example with coffeescript, angular and jade working side by side

```
doctype html
html(lang="en")
    head
        meta(charset="utf-8")
        title Test
        script(src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.1/angular.js')
        script(src='http://coffeescript.org/extras/coffee-script.js')
        style.
            input { width: 200px }

        script(type='text/coffeescript').
            app = angular.module('App', [])
            app.controller 'TestController', ($scope)->
                $scope.name = 'Angular 1.4 with Jade with coffee'
            angular.bootstrap document, ["App"]

    body
        div
            div(ng-controller="TestController")
                h2 {{name}}
                hr
                input(type="text" ng-model="name" )
```