# How to write the Angular js codes in jsfiddle?

Tags: angularjs, jsfiddle

I learn the Angularjs these days, then I using the online fiddle.net to write the angular.js codes. At first because the jsfiddle need't write the html tag. so I don't know where I should put the "ng-app" command. The link that I share doesn't work, are you get the same question?
http://jsfiddle.net/liminjun88/Jh9K7/

```
function CartController($scope){
                $scope.items=[
                    {title:'Paint pots',quantity:8,price:3.95},
                    {title:'Polka dots',quantity:17,price:12.95},
                    {title:'Pebbles',quantity:5,price:6.95}
                ];
                $scope.remove=function(index){
                    $scope.items.splice(index,1);
                }
}
```

Comment: See also [Why do I need to angular.bootstrap even when I declare ng-app=“MyApp” in JSFiddle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17496599/why-do-i-need-to-angular-bootstrap-even-when-i-declare-ng-app-myapp-in-jsfiddl/17498509#17498509)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

click on frmaework and extensions; and choose instead of domready to No Wrap - in  [image]

Answer (score 0):

You have it right, you just need to change when your script gets run, from the second dropdown in the upper left.

[Here's the modified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jh9K7/1/)

```
No wrap - in <head>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use AngularJS with option `No wrap - in <body>`

[image]

Here is the fixed JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tomepejo/mrX4L/